# How to find a joint PDF?

Tags: probability, density-function

I have this question, 
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) =  ax^2 \qquad \text{if } 1 \leq x \leq 2 \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq y \leq x
$$
I found out $~a= \frac{4}{15}$.

Now I am supposed to find marginal PDF $~f_Y(y)~$ for the cases of

$1.\quad$ If  $~0 ≤ y ≤ 1 :$

$~f_Y(y)~=$

$2.\quad$  If  $~1< y ≤ 2 :$

$~f_Y(y)~=$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the marginal PDF? Hint: it has to do with integration ...

Comment: I have the idea that it has to do something with integration, but I clearly am not sure how and what to integrate

Comment: So in order to get the marginal PDF for $y$, you imagine that $y$ is fixed, and then you just have to integrate the joint PDF over the defined interval. ($\int \ldots \, dx$)

Comment: So integrate with respect to x?

Comment: Yes. It's that simple. It's also a good idea to draw the area in the $xy$-plane (sort of like a "view from above") so that the integration limits will be clear.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. I always seem to get confused by which respect I must integrate

Comment: The way that I like to think about it, is that if you have a function $f=f(x,y)$ and you integrate it over $y$, the **result is a function of $x$**. Therefore, if we want the result to be a function of $y$, (like in this case) we must integrate over $x$.

Comment: To get a marginal density, remember that the rule is to *integrate the joint density over the **other** variable*.

Answer (score 0):

In case 1) $f_Y(y)=\int_1^{2} ax^{2}\, dx$ and in case 2) $f_Y(y)=\int_y^{2} ax^{2}\, dx$.

Comment: Thank you. Also, If I am interested in finding conditional independence, say of  1/(X^2 * Y), given that  Y=5/4. How would I approach it? Should I be using the answers that I have derived above?

Comment: If you are asking whether $\frac 1 {X^{2}}$ and $Y$ are independent given $Y=4$, yes they are independent. You can show that easily from definition without making any computation.

Answer (score 0):

The support is $\{\langle x,y\rangle: 1\leqslant x\leqslant 2, 0\leqslant y\leqslant x\}$, which may be partitioned on where $y$ is relative to $1$.

That is, the support is the  union:$$\{\langle x,y\rangle: 0\leqslant  y < 1\leqslant x\leqslant 2\}\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle:  1\leqslant y\leqslant x\leqslant 2\}$$

So, the integral is piecewise over those parts: $$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_1^2 a x^2~\mathrm d x&:& 0\leqslant y<1\\[1ex]\displaystyle\int_y^2 ax^2~\mathrm d x&:& 1\leqslant  y\leqslant  2\\[1ex]0&:& \textrm{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$